# Prefix.pch framework file not found error xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcodebuild

I'm trying to build an app using the xcodebuild command.

I'm using this commmand xcodebuild -project appNameWithExtension -target name -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release"

I have a framework added to my app and when I try to build with xcode there are no problems but when I try to use my xcodebuild command I get this error

/path/appname-Prefix.pch:16:13: fatal error: 'frameworkname/frameworkname.h' file not found

It's pointing to this line of code in my Prefix.pch file

```
 #import <frameworkname/frameworkname.h>
```

Does anyone know a way to make the xcodebuild commmand find the framework, because it seems like I'm missing something in the command to tell it where to find the framework. I can build with xcode, but I can't build from commandline, so I'm probably missing something?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What if you remove the `-project appNameWithExtension` from the command line?

Comment: Then it doesn't know which project to build? I just tried it out and it's just not building now.

Comment: How is your directory organized?  Normally its a top-level `AppName` directory containing the `.xcodeproj` bundle.  I then go into this top-level directory before using the `xcodebuild` command.

Comment: I just tried it again, and it tries to build now, but I still get the same error

Comment: I don't think the problem is that it can't find the app, I think the problem is that it can't find the framework, a framework we made, that the app uses.

Comment: And how does the app reference the framework?  Is it using a directory *relative* to `$(SRCROOT)`?

Comment: We added the framework in target Dependencies, Link Binary With Libraries and Embed Frameworks in Build Phases of the project we want to build. We also added the framework.xcodeproj to our project to reference the framework.h if that makes sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65518/discussion-between-hafax-and-trojanfoe).